# Using Crossover to install E-Sword

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 64-bit, crossover

Downloaded Crossover application. Attempted to install it but received the following error:

```
On 64-bit flavors of Debian and some Ubuntu variants, first open a
terminal and run 'sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 ; sudo apt-get
update'
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's a good idea. Do it.

Comment: That is not an error but an instruction. It is not even a question.

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as it tells you:

Find the terminal application where you have the rest of the apps.

Copy and paste:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

enter your password and press enter.

Copy and paste:

`sudo apt-get update`

and then open again Crossover and you will have no problem at all, hope you can solve your problem :)

PS: you have other alternatives also such as PlayOnLinux and Wine.